# Is there a more elegant way to Insert multiple Selects from 1 Table and Insert them into Table 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The way I am doing it right now is:

```
INSERT INTO .TempVolumePrediction
SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM StockVolumes
WHERE Country Not Like 'EE'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Country

UNION ALL

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'BUEU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM StockVolumes
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID

UNION ALL 

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'DTEU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM StockVolumes
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE' AND GroupCode = 'DT'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID

UNION ALL

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'OREU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM StockVolumes
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE' AND GroupCode = 'OR'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID
```

With each select query selecting slightly different grouped data.
So the final table will have all sales volumes by product. Then the salesvolumes grouped by state and finally sales volumes grouped by country.

Comment: You really need to put the actual queries you're using. You've oversimplified and lost some detail we need to give a good answer to the question

Comment: It depends. Is one single transaction needed? How much data is it?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the input you are propably right, I tried adding a bit more detail.

Comment: @jarlh No its not needed, my main goal is performance. Rougly 700k rows of data.

Comment: Several, smaller transactions may gain performance. I.e. keep current solution with several INSERT-SELECT in separate transactions. (Or do even smaller ones.)

Comment: @jarlh, imho, `SELECT INTO` is something to gain the best INSERT speed. Anyway OP dumps the output into a temporary table (not a #temporary)

Comment: @AlexanderVolok, point taken!

Comment: Your top two queries seem missing a FROM. Your bottom two queries prefix the tabl name with a period; I've not seen this before - is it a typo?

Comment: @CaiusJard simply a copy and paste error on my part

Comment: @Tim,  I hope that your question was answered. If so, can you consider to mark it as such one.

Answer (score 2):

UNION ALL:

```
Insert into Table 1

Select From Table 2
UNION ALL
Select From Table 2
UNION ALL
Select From Table 2
```

---

Update, if your main goal is performance consider SELECT INTO instead of INSERT INTO:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempVolumePrediction

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID,  SumOfVolume, Country,  VolumeTypeCode 
INTO dbo.TempVolumePrediction
FROM (


SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
WHERE Country Not Like 'EE'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Country

UNION ALL

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'BUEU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID

UNION ALL 

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'DTEU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM .StockVolumes
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE' AND GroupCode = 'DT'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID

UNION ALL

SELECT YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, 'OREU' AS Country, 'Stock' AS VolumeTypeCode
FROM .StockVolumes
WHERE StockVolumes.Country Not Like 'EE' AND GroupCode = 'OR'
GROUP BY YearNb, WeekNb, ProdID
) d
```

Comment: This looks a lot more economic, I will try this thanks!

Comment: @Tim, Added an update of how to get the best performance for your temporary dump

Answer (score 1):

What about using **OR**

```
Insert into Table 1
Select <columns> From Table 2
where (condition1) or (condition2)  or(condition3)
```

Comment: It will work right if each `select` statement has only rows which aren't presented in others

Comment: sometimes `WHERE .. OR..` can cause worse performance than isolated and well indexed SELECTs  via by UNION ALL

Comment: @AlexanderVolok, I agree, question has been edited so many times, so the initial answer given by me does not make much sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Some simplification may be possible if you're prepared to add a table that maps GroupCode and Country

```
CREATE TABLE GroupCodeCountry( GroupCode VARCHAR(2), Country VARCHAR(4) );
INSERT INTO GroupCodeCountry('BU', 'BUEU'); --assumed from pattern - did your query set have a typo?
INSERT INTO GroupCodeCountry('DT', 'DTEU');
INSERT INTO GroupCodeCountry('OR', 'OREU');


--this query now handles the cases where the groupcode causes an override to the country    INSERT INTO TempVolumePrediction
SELECT s.YearNb, s.WeekNb, s.ProdID, Sum(s.Volume), COALESCE(g.Country, s.Country), 'Stock'
FROM StockCountry s LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupCodeCountry g on s.GroupCode = g.GroupCode
WHERE s.Country Not Like 'EE'
GROUP BY s.YearNb, s.WeekNb, s.ProdID, COALESCE(g.Country, s.Country)
```

Performance differences would have to be tested/tuned, but this represents a simpler way of writing the queries

Comment: This looks very interesting, I actually already have a reference table that has Group and Country mapped, so I could propably implement this. I will do some testing and come back if I have questions. Thanks!

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . You don't need a separate table.  You can just use a `VALUES()` statement.

Comment: @gordonlinoff I was thinking something more permanent/extensible without redeploying code but it's a good point